# Smooth Rounded UIView Corners, Bottom Only

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer, uibezierpath

Here's the view I'm trying to mimic from the Mock-Ups I have to go with:

[image: InVision Mock Up]

Using the following code;

```
self.plusButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
let maskPathPlus = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.plusButton.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .topLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 4, height: 4))
let maskLayerPlus = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayerPlus.frame = self.plusButton.bounds
maskLayerPlus.path = maskPathPlus.cgPath
plusButton.layer.mask = maskLayerPlus

self.minusButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.minusButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.2265625, green: 0.82421875, blue: 0.34765625, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
self.minusButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
let maskPathMinus = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.minusButton.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 4, height: 4))
let maskLayerMinus = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayerMinus.frame = self.minusButton.bounds
maskLayerMinus.path = maskPathMinus.cgPath
minusButton.layer.mask = maskLayerMinus
```

I was able to achieve this:

[image: iOS Simulator Screengrab]

What can I do to smooth out those edges, as they appear to only be rounding the external edges of the view and clipping the border.  I can't do a simple .cornerRadius because the top of the ( - ) and the bottom of the ( + ) need to be squared.

Comment: move minus button top 3 line to bottom in order self.minusButton.layer.borderColor , self.minusButton.layer.borderWidth and then self.minusButton.layer.masksToBounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the + and - buttons inside of another view and put the border on the containing view. Then you can use the cornerRadius property and this will have no effect on the bottom of the + and top of the -.

```
@IBOutlet weak var upDownButton: UIView! // Contains the plus and minus buttons, constraints in storyboard

self.upDownButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
self.upDownButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.2265625, green: 0.82421875, blue: 0.34765625, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
self.upDownButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.upDownButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
```

I used constraints to layout the +/- buttons inside their container with a "equal height" constraint with a multiplier of 0.5.

The end result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Looks like that did it.  I just have to get those pesky layout constraints set right.  I took a stab at using a Stack View rather than a plain view, but it did not work.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Couple minutes and I'll share my storyboard so you can see what I did.

Comment: Complete layout in [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aef5imzh2gw08c3/PlusMinusButton.zip?dl=1) project. Won't be available forever :-)

Answer (score 3):

iOS 11 make this easier

in iOS 11 we have option called [CACornermask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cacornermask)

```
let view = UIView()
view.clipsToBounds = true
view.layer.cornerRadius = 8
view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
```

Now we can specify the what corners we need to mask.